# Are there any problems if using a shared repository between SVN and Git, without git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, gerrit

#### Background

In our distributed development teams, we have a centralized SVN repository placed remotely which is used for multiple teams committing there source code. In order to improve local performance, we have decided to use **Gerrit** (certainly Git instead of SVN) for our code review process, therefore we're setting a Git's master as a "HUB" interoperating with remote SVN repository.

#### Problem

Typically, the workaround to this problem is git-svn. However, the branch cloned via git-svn has a different folder structure rather than traditional ".git", which can NOT be recognized by Gerrit.

#### Workaround at present

So we adopt a means looking a bit naive..

1. Check out remote SVN repository.
2. At exactly the same directory as SVN working copy, git clone the counterpart git repository. So in this directory there's also a ".git" besides ".svn".

   `$ svn co http://remote.svn.repository/some_project`

   `$ cd some_project`

   `$ git clone --no-checkout git_reop ./tmp`

   `$ mv ./tmp/.git ./  # Move .git directory to SVN working copy.`

   `$ rm -rf ./tmp`

   `$ git reset --hard HEAD # This is tricky to tell git I want to use this directory as unstaged.`

#### Question

Are there any problems if using a shared repository between SVN and Git, only by pull the Git repository into the same directory as SVN working copy without git-svn?

Answer (score 2):

No real "problem" in that both system can pretty much ignore one another.
(Except git needs to ignore any `.svn/` directory, or the unique `.svn/` folder, if you are using the latest SVN 1.8)

But your git repo must have gotten all the latest changes of `http://remote.svn.repository/some_project` *before* being cloned within that repo (in order to be used by gerrit).
And you [can't retain author and dates with git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659669/how-to-retain-git-authorship-and-commit-date-when-using-git-svn-to-push-to-a-sub), I don't think a manual sync could either, which means your code review system (gerrit) might not be as efficient in those condition (i.e. reviewing changes without knowing the author).

Comment: Thank you. That is to say, it may not have any big problems as long as I have pulled the latest revision of SVN repo.

Answer (score 1):

This approach gets cumbersome quickly as the mapping between Subversion revisions and their Git counterparts is implicit; it also hard to maintain proper correspondence of ignore patterns in Subversion and Git repositories.

Alternative solution would be using [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) which is server-side bi-directional Git-SVN mirror. Below is an example on using [SubGit 2.0](http://subgit.com/eap/) (currently at EAP stage):

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url http://host.com/svn/repo GIT_REPO
# Adjust GIT_REPO/subgit/authors.txt to add author names and emails
# Specify at least one username/password at GIT_REPO/subgit/passwd
$ subgit install GIT_REPO
```

After that GIT_REPO is synchronized with your Subversion repository. You can use any Git client to work with this Git repository: all pushed commits get immediately sent to SVN.

Additionally, you can setup Gerrit server and work with it as follows:

```
$ git init .
$ git remote add subgit SUBGIT_URL
$ git fetch subgit
$ git remote add gerrit GERRIT_URL
$ git fetch gerrit
$ git commit -m 'Work in progress'
$ git push gerrit
$ git push subgit
```

As soon as the last command is issued, corresponding Git commit is translated to SVN revision by SubGit.

SubGit is a commercial product, but it's free as long as it's in EAP stage. I'm one of SubGit developers.

Comment: Is there possible to push to gerrit, after review appoved, the code is pushed to SVN automatically?  like myworkspace <-> gerrit <-> SVN

Comment: @jmuok Unfortunately, not at the moment. There are certain technical problems that don't allow us to integrate SubGit with Gerrit. Here is a feature request in our tracker: [SGT-632](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-632).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I plan to write a  Gerrit hook, like change-merged, in it invoke pre/post-receive script which provided by Subgit. is this going to be work?

Comment: @jmuok it's gonna work for the majority of possible scenarios, however, that doesn't cover certain edge cases. SubGit requires `pre-receive` semantics for the hooks that trigger synchronization code, i.e. the hook should be called just before the change is published and it should be able to cancel the operation if necessary. We can continue discussion in [SGT-632](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-632) in order to involve everyone interested.